FIWARE PEP Proxy Wilma server fails to start
I have installed the latest version of Wilma from Github on Ubuntu 22.04 following this tutorial. Unfortunately the server does not want to come up when I try to start it using sudo npm start. The following is displayed for about two minutes and then aborts:
> fiware-pep-proxy@8.3.0 start
> node ./bin/www

(node:10576) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.

I can't seem to find a log file anywhere where I could check for any issues. Could anyone give me any pointers where I could find a log file or how I could try to troubleshoot my issue?
I have included the software version below in case this helps somehow.
Ubuntu: 22.04
NPM: {
  'fiware-pep-proxy': '8.3.0',
  npm: '8.5.1',
  node: '12.22.9',
  v8: '7.8.279.23-node.56',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '72',
  nghttp2: '1.43.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '2.1.6',
  http_parser: '2.9.4',
  openssl: '1.1.1m',
  cldr: '40.0',
  icu: '70.1',
  tz: '2024a',
  unicode: '14.0'
}


Using DEBUG=* node ./bin/www I was able to see that the server threw the error message SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:331:.
According to this Github issue it is a generic protocol mismatch error. The reason was that in my config.js the port for the IdM address was still set to 3000 while SSL=true. After changing the port to 443, the server started without a hitch.
